# jsawk won't parse valid JSON

Tags: json, rest, jsawk

I'm currently developing a bash script that makes a query to a server with curl, and returns a JSON object. I'm trying to parse that object with [jsawk](https://github.com/micha/jsawk). For example, here is some data I'm trying to parse:

```
{
    "account":{
        "quota":20,
        "email":"test@example.com",
        "uuid":"12ae7a0cbd",
        "email_verified":true
    }
}
```

In terminal I'm running `cat test.json | jsawk -q 'account.quota'`.

Assume `test.json` is the above object. Every time I run that command, I always get the following error: `jsawk: js error: ReferenceError: account is not defined`, even though account is very clearly defined.

Comment: From the docs you linked https://github.com/micha/jsawk,  looks like you should be using 'this.account.quota'  or maybe 'return this.account.quota'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<test.json jsawk 'return this.account.quota'
```

I removed your useless use of `cat`.

Comment: Also, I personally highly recommend [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) instead.